# UI Toolkit в Unity

Tags: ui, unity3d-ui

Только недавно немного узнала про такой инструмент как UI Toolkit в Unity, и меня интересует такой вопрос.
Насколько целесообразно делать в нем интерфейс для таких игр, где весь геймплей основан на интерфейсе. Например, тот же кликер.
Я пока не очень хорошо познакомилась с этим инструментом, поэтому решила спросить мнение тех, кто в нем уже разбирается. Стоит ли перелезать на UI Toolkit и делать в нем целую игру (графических элементов конкретно у меня очень много, а тулкит вроде как работает намного быстрее) или допустимо продолжать использовать Unity UI и это не скажется на производительности?

Или, может быть, я пока вообще неправильно поняла принцип тулкита и использовать его для разработки подобной игры полностью не выйдет, и тут подходит только Unity UI...

К концу 2023 года все еще не так много информации про этот инструмент. Надеюсь, тут есть кто-то, кто мог бы сориентировать меня в выборе подхода. Буду очень благодарна.